# nodeEventStore publish twice

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-sourcing

I am new to event source, and I am using [nodeEventStore](https://github.com/jamuhl/nodeEventStore).

So I wrote the following simple test console application, and I found that the event will be published twice, could anyone help me to figure out why? thanks.

```
var eventstore = require('eventstore');
var storage = require('eventstore.mongoDb');
var async = require('async');

publisher = {
    publish: function(evt) {
        console.log('publishing: ');
        console.log(evt);
    }
}

var es = eventstore.createStore();

var store = storage.createStorage({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 27017,
    db: 'es'
});

es.configure(function() {
    es.use(store);
    es.use(publisher);
}).start();

async.series([
    function(cb) {store.connect(function(){cb(null);})},
    function(cb) {
        es.getEventStream('1', 0, function(err, stream) {
            stream.addEvent({id: '1', event:'add', payload:{}});
            stream.commit();
            cb(null);
        });
    }
]);
```

and the output of the above is twice which is not expected:

```
publishing:
{ id: '1', event: 'add', payload: {} }
publishing:
{ id: '1', event: 'add', payload: {} }
```

By the way, if I connect within createStorage below, it works just fine:

```
var eventstore = require('eventstore');
var storage = require('eventstore.mongoDb');
var async = require('async');

publisher = {
    publish: function(evt) {
        console.log('publishing: ');
        console.log(evt);
    }
}

var es = eventstore.createStore();

async.series([
    function(cb) {
        storage.createStorage({
            host: 'localhost',
            port: 27017,
            dbName: 'es'
        }, function(err, store) {
            es.configure(function() {
                es.use(store);
                es.use(publisher);
            });
            es.start();
            cb(null);
        });
    },
    function(cb) {
        es.getEventStream('1', 0, function(err, stream) {
            stream.addEvent({id: '1', event:'add', payload:{}});
            stream.commit();
            cb(null);
        });
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call connect...

instead of calling:

```
store.connect(function(){cb(null);})
```

i would call:

```
es.start(function(){cb(null);})
```

and not calling es.start after configuration.